# App rejected because of WebRTC?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, webrtc, appstore-approval

My app open URL in Safari to use WebRTC. App is rejected because Safari asking camera/microphone permission. Now how do i modify that popup? as per there law/rule?

[image]

> Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage
>
> We noticed that your app requests the user’s consent to access their
>   Camera and Microphone, but does not clarify the use of this feature in
>   the permission modal alert.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise the permission modal alert to
>   specify why the app is requesting access to the user's Camera and
>   Microphone￼.
>
> Resources
>
> To learn more about requesting the user’s permission to access app
>   features, visit the iOS Human Interface Guidelines. You may also want
>   to review the Technical Q&A QA1937: Resolving the Privacy-Sensitive
>   Data App Rejection page for details on how to provide a usage
>   description for permission request alerts.
>
> We look forward to reviewing your app once these issues have been
>   addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Put your requests in the app info.plist with descriptions e.g.

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
```

etc

Comment: Are you 100% sure? Because my app do not use Safari browser inside my APP but my APP open an external URL to Safari

Comment: Okay - understood - it is an external URL which the app launches - however I think it should help pass the review if you put the permissions request into the app at the start of the app launch.